# How can I overwrite lines from text file to specific lines in another file instead of appending them

Tags: java, append, overwrite

```
public class AddSingleInstance {
public void addinstances(String txtpath,String arffpath) throws IOException {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\src\\text.txt"));
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\src\\" + test.txt,true);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//String toWrite = "";
String line = null;   
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
   // toWrite += line;
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
}
 reader.close();
 fw.write(sb.toString());
 fw.flush();
 fw.close();
 }
}
```

my code is working on append lines from text file(A) to specific lines in another file(B), like

1. I
2. AM
3. ......
4. (above lines are fixed, cannot be overwriting)
5. student(New string was added from text file)
6. now(New string...)

How can I overwrite those lines into file(B) instead of appending them on B?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` to access file(B) and write to it at the desired location.

Comment: I wonder if I can create a temp file and add the fixed lines in file(B) to this temp,after running my code, I can delete the file B and rename the temp to file(B)'s name.

Comment: Now I am not sure I get your requirement. Can you give an example of fileA and fileB?

Comment: I made it as I said I copy the file B to temp file,and after I run this function and delete, then rename the temp file to file B's name.